# why is Excel requesting a password when opening a .xlsx in Excel 2003?

Tags: excel, compatibility

If I create a blank workbook in Excel 2016 (.xlsx) and protect the sheets with a password and also protect the workbook with a password and save the file WITHOUT a password required to open the file.  Then when I try and open that file in Excel 2003 it requests that I enter a password when I open the file.  I can click OK without entering a password and it opens the file no problem but why is it requesting it in the first place? It opens fine in excel 2007 onwards without requesting a password.

I have lots of clients that unfortunately still use Excel 2003 and tools that I provide need to be seamless across the different versions. This is very off putting for the client when they have no password and ring me up asking what to do (not realising they can just click OK - but that's not the point)

Answer (score 0):

Excell 2003 did not support passwords...

In the 2007 Microsoft Office system, you can use passwords to help prevent other people from opening or modifying your documents, workbooks, and presentations.

For more information on how to set passwords and for read-only recommendation for a workbook, see:

For 2007:
https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Password-protect-a-workbook-7E365A4D-3E89-4616-84CA-1931257C1517

Since 2010:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-documents-workbooks-and-presentations-ef163677-3195-40ba-885a-d50fa2bb6b68?CorrelationId=ed5c7040-e6c9-4662-801c-4218de5c30bf&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: `Tools ~ Protection ~ Protect Sheet` & `Protect Workbook`.  `Tools~Options~Security` for `Password to Open` & `Password to modify`.  `VBE ~ Tools ~ VBAProject Properties ~ Protection`.  All available in 2003.

Comment: Hi. Yes I understand adding a password to prevent a file being opened but I'm saying that the file does NOT have a password to open it - it opens fine in 2007 onwards without any request for a password but when I try an open in 2003 it requests one despite there not being one.  I can only assume it is a bug in backwards compatibility.